# Animate a div on and off screen when press a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to coding and hope someone could help me with my hopeless code skills. I'm trying to create a div that will animate on and off the screen on press a button. Here is what I've got so far.... it's probably stupidly wrong but I guess that's what this site is for.. here you go

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="test">Example Text</div>
 <script>
function myFunction()
{
    var position = test.position();
    if("#test".position<0)
    {  
    alert("hello");
    $("#test").animate({
    "left": 0
    },1000);
}else{
    $("#test").animate({
    "left": -15
    },1000);
});
}
</script>   



</body>
</html>
```

This function is called when an image is clicked. My idea was to basically tell the div to animate onto the screen if it's position value is less than 0, which I think tells it that it's off the screen. If it doesn't detect it's value is offscreen, it means the div is onscreen at the moment and so it should animate away. I'd be very grateful of any help that anyone can provide. Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: First of all, you should learn to use the JavaScript error console to see any error messages thrown the script. It's F12 in many browsers. Secondly, the most obvious errors are that you're not including  jQuery, `test` isn't defined anywhere and `if( "#test".position<0)` should be `if( $( "#test" ).position<0)` (or possibly just `if( position < 0 )`). And you're just defining `myFunction()` but never calling it from anywhere.

Comment: I see your attempting to use jQuery but you haven't included the library in your HTML file.

Comment: Hey Guys. I haven't included JQuery because I'm running this on JSFiddle... I guess I should have said that..

Comment: Check your Syntax throughout your script. There are many errors

Comment: Am I overlooking the button that calls this function as well? Like Sven Bieder said, there are syntax errors in your current code.

Comment: @user2021641 You're not supposed to put the whole document structure in jsfiddle. It should look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/cyyyp/ (then click on the JSHint button).

Comment: Can you post the link to your jsfiddle so we can see it?

Comment: Hey guys.. I know my code is covered in syntax errors, because I have no idea what I'm doing. I was hoping someone could help me out. If I could fix it myself I would, but I thought I would just post the rough outline of how I think it should work and someone can help me with the syntax, Ryan there is a button that calls this function but it's not in this posted code

Comment: Here's the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/KeE4h/46/

It sucks

Comment: I'm so bad... look how many attempts on my JSfiddle... embaressing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>

 </head>
 <body>
<div id="test">TESTTEST</div>
<input type="button" name="myButton" value="Click Me" onclick="myFunction()" />   
 <script>     
 function myFunction()
{
var divPosition = $("#test").offset();
if(divPosition.left < 0 )
{ 
$("#test").animate({
"left": 0
},1000);
 }else{
$("#test").animate({
"left": -150
},1000);
};
}
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

And CSS:

```
 #test{
     background-color:white;
     border:3px solid black;
     font-size:30px;
     position:absolute;
     left:-20%;
     top:10%;
 }
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KeE4h/48/

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time out of your day to help me. I honestly appreciate it so much.

Comment: Not a problem any time. Thats why we are here. Honestly, when I first started programming I made mistakes far worse than this. Keep at it and working hard. And keep coming backto SO for help :0)